# Shifting the origin of a large list of coordinates

Tags: c++, performance, graph, coordinate-system

**Problem and goal**

Given a large edge list file (such as 2 million nodes, 30 million edges) containing source and destination coordinates, I want to 'convert' them in such a way so that the coordinates start at 0. Hopefully the example will clear this up. ***My goal is to increase the performance (speed) of my current code.***

**Example**

input_file.txt

```
54    414
12    54
414   87
20    54
12    3
```

Output

```
0    1
2    0
1    3
4    0
2    5
```

Notice how 54 becomes 0, 414 becomes 1, 12 becomes 2, 87 becomes 3 etc. In other words: if a vertex is re-used like 54, the same coordinate will be used.

**My solution**

While my solution works fine, it is slow for a large edge list such as: [this edge list](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-pokec-relationships.txt.gz) (or [this small one for testing purposes)](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Stanford.txt.gz), and I was wondering whether there are areas to improve my code.

Essentially, I am using a dictionary (map) that keeps track of each vertex and its coordinate respectfully. If a vertex is not present in the dictionary, it uses the current coordinate and increments it for any possible new vertex.

**Code**

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "conio.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void load_graph_from_edge_list_file_to_coo(vector<int>& , vector<int>&, string);
int add_vertex_as_coordinate(vector<int>&, unordered_map<int, int>&, int, int);

int main() {
    vector<int> source_vertices;
    vector<int> destination_vertices;
    string input_file_path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\input_file.txt";
    load_graph_from_edge_list_file_to_coo(source_vertices, destination_vertices, input_file_path);

    return 0;
}

void load_graph_from_edge_list_file_to_coo(vector<int>& source_vertices, vector<int>& destination_vertices, string file_path) {
    unordered_map<int, int> map_from_edge_to_coordinate;
    int current_coordinate = 0;

    std::ifstream infile(file_path);
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int vertex_source, vertex_destination;
        if (!(iss >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination)) { 
            continue; 
        } else {
            current_coordinate = add_vertex_as_coordinate(source_vertices, map_from_edge_to_coordinate, vertex_source, current_coordinate);
            current_coordinate = add_vertex_as_coordinate(destination_vertices, map_from_edge_to_coordinate, vertex_destination, current_coordinate);
        }
    }
    infile.close();

    printf("\nTotal amount of vertices: %d", map_from_edge_to_coordinate.size());
    printf("\nTotal amount of edges: %d", source_vertices.size());
}

int add_vertex_as_coordinate(vector<int>& vertices_type, unordered_map<int, int>& map_from_edge_to_coordinate, int vertex, int coordinate) {
    if (map_from_edge_to_coordinate.count(vertex)) {
        vertices_type.push_back(map_from_edge_to_coordinate.at(vertex));

        return coordinate;
    }
    else {
        map_from_edge_to_coordinate[vertex] = coordinate;
        vertices_type.push_back(coordinate);
        coordinate++;

        return coordinate;
    }
}
```

Any tips to increase the performance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Given a large edge list file (2 million nodes, 30 million edges)` You mean a small to middle sized edge list! :-)

Comment: @user2296177 sorry - didn't even thought about that. Here is a smaller one: https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Stanford.txt.gz

Comment: @LokiAstari Haha true. :)

Comment: I don't see any output being generated y this code. Nor is there any use for `source_vertices` and `destination_vertices`. You can just print the values as you map them (no need to waste space storing them).

Comment: My apologies @LokiAstari. Indeed there was some code after the printf statements that was supposed to map them to the vectors as I need to do some work on them which I omitted from my code because that was unrelated to the problem. Indeed no output is generated (essentially I would say that if the edges and vertices size matches the dataset then it is filled in successfully).

Comment: @yuri Comments are for seeking clarification to the question, and may be deleted. Please write all suggestions for improving the code as answers — even trivial observations like avoiding `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I would describe it as "relabeling the nodes", rather than "changing coordinates to the origin", because the latter is more frequently used with translations, rotations, etc. of 2D, 3D, etc. coordinates.

Comment: How important is it that the re-mapping of the input vertices happen in an ordered fashion? In other words, does it only matter that the set of output vertices is contiguous from 0 through the number of unique vertices, regardless of their order with respect to the input; or does the order also matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you overcomplicated your problem. The easy solution that comes to mind (the third attempt I had right now) is to define a struct with a mutable element (The member we want to modify is marked mutable, as elements of a std::set are const qualified):

```
struct Vertex{
    Vertex(const size_t v) : origIndex(v) {}
    size_t origIndex;
    mutable size_t index;
    bool operator<(const Vertex& other) const {
        return origIndex< other.origIndex;
    }
};
```

Now you can simply add all the vertices to the set and then change the index afterwards.

Regarding your code, you should definitely put it into a class to better encapsulate it.

```
class normalizeGraph {
    struct Vertex{
        Vertex(const size_t v) : origIndex(v), index(v) {}
        size_t origIndex;
        mutable size_t index;
        bool operator<(const Vertex& other) const {
            return origIndex< other.origIndex;
        }
    };

private:
    std::set<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> edges;
}
```

Note that I have used the ordered versions of the set, as it allows for faster iteration and we get the ordered insertion for free in the set. Your `load_graph_from_edge_list_file_to_coo` function then becomes the constructor of the class

```
normalizeGraph(const string& file_path) {
    std::ifstream infile(file_path);
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        size_t vertex_source; 
        size_t vertex_destination;
        if (!(iss >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination)) { 
            continue; 
        } else {
            vertices.insert(Vertex(vertex_source));
            vertices.insert(Vertex(vertex_destination));
            edges.emplace_back(std::make_pair(vertex_source, vertex_destination));
        }
    }
    infile.close();

    printf("\nTotal amount of vertices: %d", map_from_edge_to_coordinate.size());
    printf("\nTotal amount of edges: %d", source_vertices.size());
}
```

The rewrite of the vertex index is now a simple loop

```
void normalizeVertices() {
    size_t newIndex = 0;
    for (auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {
        it->index = newIndex++;
    }
}
```

And rewrite the edges

```
void normalizeEdges() {
    for (auto&& edge : edges) {
        edge = std::make_pair(vertices[edge.first].index, vertices[edge.second].index);
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

You should obviously follow the suggestion of LokiAstari and optimize the while loop. Also printf is C rather than C++ so use std::cout

Put together this reads:

```
class normalizeGraph {
    struct Vertex{
        Vertex(const size_t v) : origIndex(v) {}
        size_t origIndex;
        mutable size_t index;
        bool operator<(const Vertex& other) const {
            return origIndex< other.origIndex;
        }
    };

    normalizeGraph(const string& file_path) {
        std::ifstream infile(file_path);
        size_t vertex_source; 
        size_t vertex_destination;
        while (iss >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination) {
            vertices.insert(Vertex(vertex_source));
            vertices.insert(Vertex(vertex_destination));
            edges.emplace_back(std::make_pair(vertex_source, vertex_destination));
        }
        infile.close();

        std::cout << "\nTotal amount of vertices: " << vertices.size();
        std::cout << "\nTotal amount of edges: " << edges.size();
    }

    void normalizeEdges() {
        for (auto&& edge : edges) {
            edge = std::make_pair(vertices[edge.first].index, vertices[edge.second].index);
        }
    }

    void normalizeVertices() {
        size_t newIndex = 0;
        for (auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {
            it->index = newIndex++;
        }
    }

private:

    std::set<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> edges;
}
```

## EDIT2:

The `operator[]` of a std::set only takes the key as a value. However, one can use `find()` and overload the comparison operator. The solution is as follows

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point timer;

class normalizeGraph1 {
public:
    struct Vertex{
        Vertex(const size_t v) : origIndex(v) {}
        size_t origIndex;
        mutable size_t index;
        bool operator<(const Vertex& other) const {
            return origIndex< other.origIndex;
        }
    };

    normalizeGraph1(const std::string& file_path) {
        std::ifstream infile(file_path);
        size_t vertex_source;
        size_t vertex_destination;
        while (infile >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination) {
            vertices.insert(Vertex(vertex_source));
            vertices.insert(Vertex(vertex_destination));
            edges.emplace_back(std::make_pair(vertex_source, vertex_destination));
        }
        infile.close();

        std::cout << "Total amount of vertices: " << vertices.size() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Total amount of edges: " << edges.size() << "\n";

        /* Take the time of the simulation */
        timer start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        normalizeVertices();
        normalizeEdges();
        timer end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double dif = 1E-3*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( end - start ).count();
        std::cout << "Normalization took " << dif << " seconds" << "\n";
    }

    void normalizeEdges() {
        for (auto&& edge : edges) {
            edge = std::make_pair(vertices.find(edge.first)->index, vertices.find(edge.second)->index);
        }
    }

    void normalizeVertices() {
        size_t newIndex = 0;
        for (auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {
            it->index = newIndex++;
        }
    }

private:
    std::set<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> edges;
};
```

For the provided sample file this takes 2.6s on my machine. However, there is a much better solution

## Solution2

The underlying problem is, that we have to traverse the edges on after of the vertices. This is highly suboptimal, as there are generally many more edges than vertices. The solution is to store the pointer to the vertexIndex in the map rather then the vertexIndex itself

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
class normalizeGraph2 {
public:
    normalizeGraph2(const std::string& file_path) {
        std::ifstream infile(file_path);
        size_t vertex_source;
        size_t vertex_destination;
        while (infile >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination) {
            vertices.emplace(std::make_pair(vertex_source, vertex_source));
            vertices.emplace(std::make_pair(vertex_destination,vertex_destination));
            edges.emplace_back(std::make_pair(&vertices[vertex_source], &vertices[vertex_destination]));
        }
        infile.close();

        std::cout << "Total amount of vertices: " << vertices.size() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Total amount of edges: " << edges.size() << "\n";

        /* Take the time of the simulation */
        timer start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        normalizeVertices();
        timer end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double dif = 1E-3*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( end - start ).count();
        std::cout << "Normalization took " << dif << " seconds" << "\n";
    }

    void normalizeVertices() {
        size_t newIndex = 0;
        for (auto&& vertex : vertices) {
            vertex.second = newIndex++;
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<size_t,size_t> vertices;
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t*, size_t*>> edges;
};
```

This only takes 0.018s on my machine, which is considerable faster than the other approach. The only caveat is, that you have to dereference the values of the edges.

```
void printEdges() {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < 10; ++index) {
       std::cout <<  *edges[index].first << "\t" << *edges[index].second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify why you made index `mutable`? Just add a small sentence to explain your reasoning.

Comment: Amazing miscco, truly appreciate it. Will get back to this really soon!

Comment: @yuri the elements of a set are const qualified, so you can only modify elements of a struct in a set if they are defined as `mutable`

Comment: @yuri, elements of set are immutable. Thus, one needs to have `mutable` on member they want to modify.

Comment: Truly appreciate it, missco. Just a small question (I'm a terrible c/c++ newbie, my apologies): the part of the line `vertices[edge.first].index`and `vertices[edge.second].index` inside the normalizeEdges() function gives me the semantic error: `no operator "[]" maches these operands`. I tried several ways to fix this, but was unsuccessfull. Not sure whether I might miss an include though for this. Furthermore, I assume that I first have to call normalizeVertices() and then normalizeEdges() correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the sleep was strong in this one. The map expects an object of type vertex for the operator[], which I overlooked. One solution would be to search for Vertex(vertices[edge.second].index). However, there is an even better slution, that i will present when i have time later

Comment: @CarrotCake I fixed the code and added a better solution

Comment: I'll have more detailed feedback later, but for now: what's with the emplace-that's-not-an-emplace? The whole point of calling emplace is to avoid a double-call to the value constructor, but you've called it explicitly anyway. Can you not simply omit make_pair?

Comment: @miscco - More importantly: though it isn't stated explicitly, the OP's original intent is (probably) to do an ordered re-mapping of the vertices as they appear in the input. Your solution performs the re-mapping on a map object whose order is based not on order of appearance, but order of the vertex values themselves. This is not the same thing.

Comment: Also: rather than writing `vertices[vertex_source]` / `vertices[vertex_destination]` and issuing another couple of lookups, you should simply use the iterators returned from `emplace`.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can see that will speed stuff up is this part:

```
string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int vertex_source, vertex_destination;
    if (!(iss >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination)) {
```

There is a lot of copying from `line` to `iss`. This provides some good error checking and correction ability. But does slow the code down.

Replacing the above with

```
while (iss >> vertex_source >> vertex_destination)
{
```

results in a 10% speed improvement in my code (though I took out the vectors; I did not need them).

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid `using namespace std;` as it brings in *everything* declared in that namespace and can lead to collisions.

If you use something from a certain namespace a lot, consider `using std::vector;` (as an example) instead. Otherwise you can simply qualify something with `std::foo` as you did in your code with `std::ifstream`

See these links for a more in-depth explanation

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903542/what-is-namespace-pollution
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236404/what-is-using-namespace-pollution

Comment: Thank you, yuri. I'll make sure to think about that in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You missed

```
#include <vector>
```

I had to add that, and remove the include of `"conio.h"` (which wasn't provided, but apparently not required).  I also removed the second `#include <iostream>` and the `#pragma` (you should explain the purpose, in case there's an equivalent for the rest of us).

Having done that (and minor change to read the filename from arguments), I get

```
Total amount of vertices: 1632803
Total amount of edges: 30622564
29.29user 0.20system 0:29.50elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 309840maxresident)k
```

I get almost exactly the same speed from this simpler version, which acts as a conventional filter, taking input from stdin and writing to stdout:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

using label_t = unsigned int;

class Replace
{
    std::unordered_map<label_t,label_t> replacement = {};

public:
    Replace() = default;
    label_t operator[](label_t id)
    {
        auto r = replacement.insert({id, replacement.size()});
        return r.first->second;
    }
};

int main() {
    Replace mapping;

    label_t from, to;
    while (std::cin >> from >> to) {
        from = mapping[from];
        to = mapping[to];
        std::cout << from << "  " << to << "\n";
    }
}
```

It's not any faster, but it does seem to be clearer.  It's possible that the next thing to try is to avoid converting to and from integers when reading and writing the values.